Spring Jackson JsonDeserialize not working in 2nd level of nested class
In my case JsonDeserialize works well in TournamentRequestDTO and PrizeInfo, but not working inside  PrizeGroup. Not sure where problem is and what I am doing wrong. I also tried to make custom setters inside these classes - same issue, setters not working in PrizeGroup, but works well in TournamentRequestDTO and PrizeInfo.
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TournamentRequestDTO {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("gameplayMode")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = EnumDeserializer.class)
    private TournamentGameplayMode gameplayMode;

    @JsonProperty("prizesInfo")
    private @Valid PrizeInfo prizeInfo;
    
    ...

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class PrizeInfo {

        @JsonProperty("currency")
        @JsonDeserialize(using = EnumDeserializer.class)
        private TournamentCurrency currency;

        @JsonProperty("prizes")
        private List<@Valid PrizeGroup> prizes;
        
        ...

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @AllArgsConstructor
        public static class PrizeGroup {
            @JsonProperty("type")
            @JsonDeserialize(using = EnumDeserializer.class)
            private PrizeType type;

            @JsonProperty("name")
            private String name;
            
            ...
        }
    }
}

I tried to modify deserializators, I tried to write setters inside PrizeGroup, I tried to use one prize instead of list - breakpoints not triggered, Jackson using default inner methods inside PrizeGroup an I can overwrite them to use my custom classes and methods.
public class EnumDeserializer<T extends Enum<T>> extends JsonDeserializer<T> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private Class<T> enumType;

    public EnumDeserializer() {
    }

    private EnumDeserializer(Class<T> enumType) {
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        String value = parser.getValueAsString().toUpperCase();
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(this.enumType, value);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(String.join("", "Value '", parser.getValueAsString(),
                    "' not allowed for field '", parser.getParsingContext().getCurrentName(), "' enumeration"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) {
        return new EnumDeserializer(property.getType().getRawClass());
    }
}

test:
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void givenTournamentRequest_whenPassOrdinaryValueToPrizeType_thenThrowException() {
        TournamentRequestDTO tournamentRequestDTO = TournamentRequestDtoTestData
                .getDefaultTournamentRequestDto()
                .build();

        String requestBody = JsonUtils.serialize(tournamentRequestDTO);
        requestBody = requestBody.replaceFirst("\"type\":\"REAL_MONEY\"", "\"type\":3");

        ExceptionResponse actualExceptionResponse =
                HttpTestHelper.performPostRequest(mockMvc, ENDPOINT_TOURNAMENT_UPDATE, requestBody, ExceptionResponse.class);

        String expectedMessage = String.join("", "Validation failed with error: " +
                        "JSON parse error: Value '3' not allowed for field 'currency' enumeration.");

        assertEquals(expectedMessage, actualExceptionResponse.getMessage());
    }

no error returned, as custom deserializer not used for type field:
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1]


What do you mean "it's not working"? Can you provide some exception or results of your tests?

@MarcoTizzano updated description

I found answer: Jackson library requires that the classes it operates on have a default no-args constructor. This is because Jackson instantiates the class before setting its fields using the setters or direct access. The @NoArgsConstructor annotation from Lombok automatically generates a no-args constructor for your class, allowing Jackson to function as expected.
